# How to get the state of the extra mouse buttons?

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to get the state of the extra mouse buttons? When I say extra, I mean **NOT** those buttons:

- Left click
- Right click
- Middle click
- Scroll down
- Scroll up
- Previous
- Next
- Tilt left
- Tilt right

More like gaming mouse extra.

Comment: [Windows supports a mouse with five buttons.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-mouse-input#xbuttons) In addition to the left, middle, and right buttons there are XBUTTON1 and XBUTTON2. For extra gaming mouse buttons, they seems handled by specified device drivers. Are you developing a driver?

Comment: I would prefer not... but okay I guess that answers my question. It is not possible without making a driver on Windows :(